# 'Correct' way to use git project

Tags: python, git, licensing

**Situation** Someone has coded an algorithm in Python and has made it available under GNU GPL as a Python module on Bitbucket.

**Question** The algorithm is complete and requires a user-specific function that I need to code myself. Since I'm new to Git, I don't know exactly how I should proceed. Atm I feel overwhelmed by forking, cloning and branching, so I would appreciate if somebody more experienced told me what they would do? Also, is it ethical to clone their Git project, add my stuff and upload it on another service like Github?

Comment: You should google  "how to use git" and carefully read the top result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork, copy, change, and redestribute since this algorithm is published in GPL, but you should keep your redestributed code under a GPL compatible license.

Clone the project to your machine, you can do it following those steps:

- Navigate to the repository in Bitbucket.
- Click the Clone button. Copy
- the clone command (either the SSH format or the HTTPS). If you are using the SSH protocol,  you must make sure your public key is in Bitbucket and loaded on the local system you are cloning to.
- Launch a terminal.
- Change to the local directory  where you want to   clone your
  Bitbucket repository.
- Paste the command you copied from Bitbucket, for example:

  ```
  $ git clone git@bitbucket.org:tutorials/mydvcsproject.git
  ```

If you were successful, a new sub-directory appears on your local drive. This directory has the same name as the Bitbucket repository that you cloned. The clone contains the files and metadata that Git requires to maintain the changes you make to the source files.